# Unexpected keyword error in simple F# code

Tags: f#

I'm creating a tiny function that will generate an alphanumeric string randomly like so

```
open System

let randomStr (len : int) : string =
    let rand = new Random() 
    let ch = Array.concat [| [|'a' .. 'z'|];[|'A' .. 'Z'|];[|'0' .. '9'|] |]
    let sz = Array.length ch in
    System.String(Array.init len (fun _ -> ch.[rand.Next sz]))

let e = randomStr 5
printf "%s" e
```

I seem to keep receiving the following error and I have no clue as to why

```
error FS0010: Unexpected keyword 'let' or 'use' in expression. Expected 'in' or other token.
```

Comment: This compiles and runs for me in an editor and via `dotnet fsi`. Could you give some more info about your environment? Which line are you seeing the error?

Comment: I'm running this in visual studio 2017. The error appears at the "let ch" line.

Comment: First things first -- definitely upgrade. VS 2017 has many issues (including F# tools) that have long since been improved in the past years.

My bet is maybe you have some kind of encoding setting turned on that's screwing with the F# compiler. I recommend a fresh VS 2019 or VS 2022 preview install.

Comment: Yeah this is running just fine from the command line. Definitely is a VS issue. Thanks

Comment: By the way, you should avoid creating new `Random` instances all the time. Instead, create one, once, and pass it in to `randomStr`. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-5.0#Multiple)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have [lightweight syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/verbose-syntax) turned off via `#light "off"`. I've reproduced the same error outside of Visual Studio [here](https://try.fsharp.org/#?code=MQGwlg5gFgLgBAIgPYDMUILAChtIA4CmAdnAMoCeAzjAQLbbYgHwBOAhkQCZK2kwtwAFExIAuOGCIwAlHHHUWkiHAC82OBrhNWHTqrhECAdzgAlXT0Gz1m7XADGUfQEEW7cgDp7SIvbbwAbQAfOGCAcjYwuA8PODCALzCggF0AbnDnKJi4gC0ktPCABizYsIBOfLgUmw07SniXNzZPEQgYJ0cJIhqyKhpaDz5FIghBV3cPSTB4ESEUAFcSAH04AFoAPgcoDwD2Lg8AOQIAD3h65OlpBiw7An097l5+OABWbDxhmBREAFJKBDgBCAA&html=DwCwLgtgNgfAsAKAAQqaApgQwCb2ag4CdMTJcMABwFp0BHAVwEsA3AXgCIBhAewDsw6AdQAqAT0roOSAMb9BAzoIAeYAPThoAbhkhMAJwDOJNgzAAzagA4OeQhqy5EhAEY9sYu6mBq3HvD6asEA&css=Q). Try removing the `#light` directive. There might also be some setting in VS2017 that disables lightweight syntax, but I don't have a copy handy that I can try. Lightweight syntax is now considered the norm in F#, so there's rarely any need for the old verbose style.